# Google Cloud Installation: Hostname unresolved

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Okay, feel really dumb as I can't even install Google Cloud SDK. Started using command line and then moved to the installer. I got a "Download Failed:Resolving Hostname" Error. There seems to be nothing in the guides and any youtube videos say it installs easily - just keep clicking next?!?

Why am I being asked to set up a network proxy?

I'm using VPN? Could that be the issue?

Thanks in advance

[image: Installer Error]

[image: CommandLineError]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was the VPN. Annoying. Whilst posting this it occurred to me so I tried with the VPN disconnected and yipdy do dar, it worked.